# Retrieving values of PersonId while using membership

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I am using ASP.NET Membership in my MVC3 application.

I have used a `PersonId` variable to declare relation ship between `UserId` and `PersonId` to insert values into a different table which contains all the information of the user who has a particular `UserId`.

With this it is obvious that a person having certain `UserId` would have a definite `PersonId`.

Like membership store certain values in the Cookies I want to Store my `PersonId` in as well.

How can i do that?

The obvious benefit of this approach is that i would save a Database call because the main thing I am using is `PersonId`.

I want to know the best and most secure way to do that.

Please suggest.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you will want to look at :

---

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs(v=vs.85).aspx

ASP.NET Profile Properties Overview

---

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/281602/ASP-NET-Profile-Provider

ASP.NET Profile Provider